# Convert string to double (NOT decimal)

Tags: mysql, casting, double

I have a table of double precision values, and I need to insert new values calculated from strings with numeric meaning.

MySQL doesn't seem to allow such conversion:

```
select cast('3.33' as double);
```

(error)

```
select cast('3.33' as decimal(3,2));
```

(works, but it's not what I need).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Workaround:

```
select '3.33' + 0.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL does not allow casting to double. If you are worried about the digits on the right side of the decimal point, use a higher precision decimal something like decimal(30,30). The other solution would be do the calculations on the code level and then insert the final double value in mysql directly.

Comment: the problem is that i need the values as floating-point in order to insert in a given table, that can't be changed.

Comment: this is not really answer of question .. you should comment to question ...